# Is there a way to minimize this SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to minimize this SQL query

```
delete from [empDetail] 
where empDetailID in
         (select empDetailID 
          from 
              (select * 
               from [empDetail] 
               where ItemID in 
                        (select ItemID 
                         from [empDetail] 
                         where QuoteID in 
                                  (select QuoteID 
                                   from [emp] 
                                   where Title = 'Remark' and UserID = 12345)
                         group by ItemID
                         having COUNT(ItemID) > 1) 
              ) a
          where empSelectionID in (2,3,4,5)
      );
```

Comment: Using a `JOIN` you might make your query more understandable at the very least.

Comment: What do you mean with 'minimize'? less code or make it faster to run?

Comment: its working fine but i was looking for less code(@idstam)

Answer (score 1):

This might work,

```
delete * from [empDetail]  as b
inner join [emp]  as a on a.QuoteID  = b.QuoteID 
where Title = 'Remark' and UserID = 12345
and empSelectionID in (2,3,4,5)
group by b.ItemID
having COUNT(ItemID) > 1
```

Comment: He's deleting from `empDetail`, not `emp`, so I doubt it.